# I would like a separate process to when django starts - is there an accepted way of doing this?

Tags: django, startup, hook

I was thinking of making settings.py start the process but this seemed slightly ugly.

I don't really want to make make custom start up scripts, nor can I really make the starting of this process lazy.

Comment: The reasons are a little convoluted :). I need to use some libraries from IronPython but invoking ironpython syncrhonously is too slow due to start up times - thus a service is used - something needs to start this service. Of course it would be better if this were all in python...

Comment: The reason lazy loading is not possible is that this is for a webservice which expected response within a given time frame, and will send duplicate requests otherwise. At the moment I've decided to just use lazy loading and have the first request fail

Comment: And yes - hosting the service entirely in IronPython would probably be a good option if it could be done.

Comment: So recoding in C# it is then...

Comment: The title of the question doesn't make sense. Is there a typo?

Comment: @tat.wright Application servers generally aren't a good place for managing process lifecycles. That's why I said tail wagging the dog. I don't think this is a shortcoming of Python/Django or something that could be overcome by switching to C#. Your IronPython process sounds like a daemon process.

Comment: @tat.wright So my suggestion is to use facilities of your OS to manage the lifecycle of a daemon process, not Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to register a listener to the "class-prepared" signal on one of your model classes and fire your process from there. However, I think the need to do this is most likely a design smell, or a case of the tail wagging the dog.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#class-prepared

I'd be curious to know why your design calls for this, but that may get us off-topic here.